# ASP.NET MVC: Logging out in the view once called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a logout action which directs to a logout view. The user information is still displayed after clicking the logout button. I fully logout after I go to a different url, why is this? How do I handle this? Client-side redirect?

Action:

```
    public ViewResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a javascript event to redirect the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the authentication token:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Context.Response.Cookies.Item(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName).Expires = Date.Now;
return RedirectToAction("LogOut");
```

Also, make sure the page is not cached:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Session.Abandon(); after the logout

Comment: not work.. The information still shows up in view after rendering.